# $\lim_{n\to\infty}{(\text{median of}\prod_{i=1}^n{X_i})}$ where $X_i$ are independent uniform random real numbers from $0$ to $e$

Tags: random-variables, density-function, infinite-product, median

Take $n$ independent uniform random real numbers from $0$ to $e$ and find their product. Do this an infinite number of times and find the median of the products. What does the median approach as $n\to\infty$?

Playing with excel and its random number function, the median of the product does not seem to vary much with $n$. For $n=2$, I worked out (by considering the area under the curve $xy=m$) that the median of the product is the solution to $e^2-3m+m\ln{m}=\dfrac{e^2}{2}$, approximately 1.379. The limit seems to be slightly greater than this, around 1.395.

[Here](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Emaxog/publications2/ProductRVs.pdf) is an article that gives the probability density function of the product of $n$ independent uniform random variables. I've tried integrating the pdf from $0$ to $m$ and setting that equal to $\frac{1}{2}$, without much progress.

Context: no specific context; I just thought of the question and found that I cannot answer it.

My background: high school math teacher. (I suspect that the justification of the answer to my question may be beyond my  ability to comprehend, but perhaps others may benefit.)

Comment: I think the median of the log is the log of the median, so perhaps you can look at $\text{median} \sum \log X$

Comment: I haven't checked this, but have you checked if the PDF in the document is valid when you assume $0^0=1$?

Comment: @BenjaminWang I just checked, and yes it's valid under that assumption, thanks! I'll edit my question.

Comment: Using the probability density function given in the link in the question, the median $m$ satisfies $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\int_0^{m}\frac{(n-\ln{x})^{n-1}}{e^n(n-1)!}dx}=\frac{1}{2}$. Using desmos, it is apparent that that $m=e^{1/3}$, but I have not been able to prove this.

Comment: I am falsely tempted by @user619894's comment.  If $Y=\log(X)$ then $Y$ has a shifted, reverse exponential distribution with mean $0$ and variance  $1$ since $(1-Y) \sim Exp(1)$ .  So we can apply the central limit theorem and say that $\frac1{\sqrt{n}} \sum Y_i$ converges in distribution to $N(0,1)$ as $n$ increases.  Not only is its mean $0$, but its median also approaches $0$ given the symmetry of the limiting distribution. 
Then $\exp(\frac1{\sqrt{n}} \sum Y_i)=\left(\prod X_i\right)^{1/{\sqrt{n}}}$ has a limiting log-normal distribution with median $1$.  But $\prod X_i$ need not.