# If $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{x^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}$ for large $n$, approximate $x$ in terms of $n$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, taylor-expansion, exponential-function, approximation

Split the Maclaurin series for $e^x$ into two sub-series - the first $n$ terms, and the remainder - then equate the two sub-series. What is a good approximation for $x$, for large $n$?

Since $e^x=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}$, we have $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{x^k}{k!}=\frac{1}{2}e^x$.

Experimenting with desmos, it seems that $x\approx n-\frac{1}{3}$ for even or odd $n$, and $x\approx -0.28n-0.4$ for even $n$. Other than that, I do not know how to approach this question.

(Context: I was trying to answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4476551/lim-n-to-infty-textmedian-of-prod-i-1nx-i-where-x-i-are-indepe?noredirect=1#comment9385231_4476551), but I think the question in this post is interesting by itself.)

Comment: Congratulations and $\to +1$

Comment: I find the downvote puzzling.  This is an interesting and fairly natural question (+1).  The OP explained it  and the context for it very clearly and presented reasonable numerical approximations to the result.  What more could be asked for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The root of $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}=\frac{e^x}{2}$ is close to $n+\frac{2}{3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4374221/the-root-of-sum-k-0n-fracxkk-fracex2-is-close-to-n-frac23)

Comment: @Gary Partially. It addresses the positive root, but not the negative root.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [equivalent](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.4.E10) to the asymptotic inversion with respect to $x$ and for large $n$ the normalised upper incomplete gamma function $Q$: $$
Q(n,x) = \frac{1}{2}.
$$ From [this result](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.12.E22), we have $$
x \sim n-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{8}{405n}+\frac{184}{25515n^2}+\frac{2248}{3444525n^3}+\ldots,
$$
as $n\to +\infty$. To find the negative root when $n$ is even, we can proceed as follows. For the lower incomplete gamma function $\gamma$, we have
$$
\frac{{\gamma (n + 1,nx)}}{{(nx)^n e^{ - nx} }} = \frac{{n\gamma (n,nx)}}{{(nx)^n e^{ - nx} }} - 1.
$$
Thus, [by this result](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.11.E18),
$$
\frac{{n\gamma (n,nx)}}{{(nx)^n e^{ - nx} }} = \frac{1}{1-x}+\mathcal{O}\!\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)
$$
for $x<0$ and $n\to +\infty$. For the normalised lower incomplete gamma function this means
$$
P(n,nx)= \frac{{(nx)^n e^{ - nx} }}{{\Gamma (n + 1)}}\frac{1}{1-x}\left( 1+\mathcal{O}\!\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \right),
$$
for $x<0$ and $n\to +\infty$. Employing Stirling's formula yields
$$
P(n,nx)= \frac{{x^n e^{n(1 - x)} }}{{\sqrt {2\pi n} }}\frac{1}{1-x}\left( 1+\mathcal{O}\!\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)  \right),
$$
for $x<0$ and $n\to +\infty$. Now the problem is equivalent to solving $P(n,nx)=\frac{1}{2}$ for even $n$ and negative $x$. If $n$ is even, the above asymptotics may be written
$$
P(n,nx) = \frac{{e^{n(1 - x + \log \left| x \right|)} }}{{\sqrt {2\pi n} }}\frac{1}{1-x}\left( 1+\mathcal{O}\!\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)
$$
for $x<0$ and $n\to +\infty$. A first approximation to the solution of the original problem is thus
$$
x_0 n=(-0.2784645438\ldots )n,
$$
where $x_0=-0.2784645438\ldots$ is the unique negative root of $1-x+\log|x|=0$. A better approximation follows by solving
$$
(1 - x + \log \left| x \right|) = \frac{1}{{2n}}\log \left( {\frac{{(1-x)^2\pi n}}{2}} \right).
$$
Writing $x = x_0  + \xi$, using linear approximation, and taking $1-x\approx 1-x_0$ on the right-hand side, we find
$$
\frac{{1 - x_0 }}{{x_0 }}\xi  \approx \frac{1}{{2n}}\log \left( {\frac{{(1-x_0)^2\pi n}}{2}} \right) \Longrightarrow \xi  \approx \frac{{x_0 }}{{2(1 - x_0 )n}}\log \left( {\frac{{(1-x_0)^2\pi n}}{2}} \right).$$ Hence, a second approximation to the solution of the original problem is
\begin{align*}
& x_0 n + \frac{{x_0 }}{{2(1 - x_0 )}}\log \left( {\frac{{(1-x_0)^2\pi n}}{2}} \right) \\ & = (-0.2784645438\ldots)n +(-0.1089058528\ldots)\log \left(  (2.5674219652\ldots)n  \right). 
\end{align*}
It is possible to obtain higher approximations using more terms from the asymptotics of $P(n,nx)$, but the procedure becomes tedious.

Comment: Great, thank you! So the negative solution does not have a linear asymptote after all.

Comment: I think this answer helps us answer a related question: Approximate, in terms of $n$, the solution to $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\frac{x^k}{k!}}=0$ for even $n$. (Same first approximation as the one in this answer.)

Comment: @Dan For the problem you wrote in your comment, there is a beautiful theory for complex roots. See, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51586/approximating-roots-of-the-truncated-taylor-series-of-exp-by-values-of-the-la).

Comment: This is nice (as usual !)

Comment: What could be done with the approximation $$\Gamma \left(2 p,-\frac{p}{2}\right)\sim -\frac{1}{27} e^p p^{2 p-2} (9 p+1)\sim -\frac{1}{3} e^p p^{2 p-1}$$ which is quite good ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Not much, I am afraid. At least not in the context of this particular problem.

Comment: Bad news ! I was quite happy with it. Thanks and cheers :-(

Answer (score 11):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{x^k}{k!}=\frac{e^x \Gamma (n,x)}{\Gamma (n)}$$
$$\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}=\frac{e^x (\Gamma (n)-\Gamma (n,x))}{\Gamma (n)}$$ So, we need to solve for $x$ the equation
$$2\Gamma (n,x)=\Gamma (n)$$ Numerically, it is better to look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=\log (2 \Gamma (n,x))-\log (\Gamma (n))$$ As you noticed, the solution is close to $n$.

If we make one single iteration of Newton method with $x_0=n$, we have
$$x_1=n+e^n n^{1-n} \Gamma (n,n) (\log (2 \Gamma (n,n))-\log (\Gamma (n)))$$ Looking [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.11#v), there is nice approximation : to first order
$$\Gamma (n,n)\sim  n^{n-1}\, e^{-n}\Bigg[\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \sqrt{n}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{12} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2n}}   +O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \Bigg]$$ and then, guess what,
$$x_1 \sim n-\frac 13 +\frac{1}{9 \sqrt{2 \pi n}} +\frac{1}{81 \pi  n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{\frac 32}}\right)$$

Just a few checks
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 5  & 4.68728 &  4.67091 \\
 10 & 9.68108 &  9.66871 \\
 15 & 14.6784 &  14.6680 \\
 20 & 19.6768 &  19.6677 \\
 25 & 24.6757 &  24.6675 \\
 30 & 29.6749 &  29.6673 \\
 35 & 34.6743 &  34.6672 \\
 40 & 39.6738 &  39.6672 \\
 45 & 44.6734 &  44.6671 \\
 50 & 49.6730 &  49.6671
\end{array}
\right)$$

Taking more terms, we have
$$x_1 \sim n-\frac 13 +\frac{1}{9 \sqrt{2 \pi n}}+\frac{5-12 \pi }{405 \pi  n}+\frac{20+51 \pi }{4860 \sqrt{2} \pi ^{3/2}n^{3/2}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ which, for $n=5$ gives $x_1=4.68177$.

**Edit**

For the case where $n=2p$, we need to solve
$$g(x)=\log (2 \Gamma (2p,x))-\log (\Gamma (2p))$$ As you noticed, the solution is close to $-\frac 1 2p$. Doing the same as above
$$x_1=-\frac 1 2p+2^{2 p-1} e^{-p/2} p^{1-2 p} \Gamma \left(2 p,-\frac{p}{2}\right) \left(\log(\Gamma (2 p))-\log \left(2 \Gamma \left(2
   p,-\frac{p}{2}\right)\right)\right)$$ Using another approximation given in [1](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.11#v),
$$\Gamma \left(2 p,-\frac{p}{2}\right)\sim -\frac{1}{27} e^p p^{2 p-2} (9 p+1)\sim -\frac{1}{3} e^p p^{2 p-1}$$

*At this point, at least for the time being, I am stuck.*

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! Any insight into the negative root ($x\approx -0.28n-0.4$)? I am curious about what those coefficients actually are.

Comment: Very nice question and answer, +1 to both.

Comment: Wonderful stuff!